# Angular HTTP call return values into two properties based on status

Tags: angular, http

I've got a Model called Project, in that model I have a property called ACTIVE which is either true or false.

In my Angular 8 class I'm performing an API get call for all projects and would like to sort the returned values into two categories based on this true or false status, so, I end of showing a list of active projects and a list of inactive projects (I've built a toggle function for later use)

This is my ngOnInit function

```
//Properties
activeProjects;
inactiveProjects;



ngOnInit() {
    this._projectService.getAllProjects().subscribe(
      response => {
        // Trying to sort response into the two properties above
      },
      error => console.log(error['message'])
    )
  }
```

I think this is a switch or map thing but I'm pretty new to this so I'm a little confused on what to do next

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems so easy that you get a free pass on this one, but next time, please try to do it on your own at least once.

```
response => {
  this.activeProjects = response.filter(v => v.active);
  this.inactiveProjects = response.filter(v => !v.active);
},
```

(Of course, adapt this to your own case, for instance it might be `response.data.filter` or smth like that)

Comment: Using filter you can achieve this.... @maryannah is absolutely correct....

Comment: Ahh. That was easy! Thanks so much for the help. Building a mental model of this whole thing, this helps a lot!

Comment: Now I'm getting errors. The response is an object, not array which filter is a function of. Wondering if I should map the data to array in the component or on the server

Comment: @mikevarela this is anothier question, you didn't close this one altough you got the answer, and I have explicitly stated in my answer that this would happen. I really can't do anything more here, and even if I wanted, I'm not even sure I would/should do it.

Comment: Hey. Wanted to say thanks for the help. Wished the rude comment at the end wasn’t made, but, thanks again for the help

Comment: @mikevarela no problem, and it's not rude (compared to other comments I have made before), sorry if you felt offended. You have to understand that SOF users tend to ask for us to do their jobs instead of asking for help, so we have to set boundaries, otherwise they get very needy.